# Print subsets of set containing no.s in powers of 3

Tags: java

Consider the set containing no.s in powers of 3 as `{1,3,9,27,....}`. Now consider a set made of subsets of this set as `{{},{1},{3},{1,3},{9},{1,9},{3,9},{1,3,9}...}`

We are supposed to get the subset at nth position and print its elements in increasing order , `n` being the input..

eg: subset at 4th position `(n=4)` is `{1,3}`. Also n can be 19 digits long..

I am stuck at figuring out the order of power sets. Also will the apt data type be BigInteger in java?

Set of test cases:

```
n = 14 op {1,9,27}
n = 783 op {3,9,27,6561,19683}
n = 1125900981634049 op {59049, 3486784401,205891132094649, 717897987691852588770249}
```

Comment: 64 bit should be enough to store the numbers, so `Long` is OK, no need for BigInteger.

Comment: what have you done??

Comment: so, what do you have got so far? anyways, i think this is the wrong place to get their examination questions done.

Comment: @GaborSch Long is to short. She said that n can be 19 digits, but java has only a signed Long which max value is 2^63 and this number is 19 digits long, but smaller than 9999999999999999999. And the testcases also contains much bigger numbers, so u you have to use a BigInteger.

Comment: @kai then, why 19? Why not 20, or arbitrary number? Long can store some 19-digit numbers (not all, because it's signed, if it were unsigned, it would be no question)

Comment: BTW, for calculations, you will need BigInteger, unfortunately, because  e.g. 717897987691852588770249 won't fit in a Long datatype.

Comment: I have generated the set (easy though), have used BigInteger for the same, not sure of the answer , I am stuck in the logic for generating power sets in that specific order.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple.

Notice that the presence of the bit `i` in the number indicates a number `3^i` in the set.

So, you iterate through the bits of your `n`, and if you find a bit set, you add the `3^i` to your set.

Calculation of the `3^i` is easy, if you start from 1, and multiply by 3 each loop.

From this you should be able to write the code.

`n` should be of type `long` IMO, because of the bit operations. `3^i` should be treated as `BigInteger` because it can be as big as 3^63.

Comment: The problem is not in generating the set but the power set. I am not able to figure out the order in which elements in power set appears.. like acc to me , first all single digits then combination of two digits, three digit so on should appear.

Comment: Could you please explain why this approach works? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Notice with your sets `{{},{1},{3},{1,3},{9},{1,9},{3,9},{1,3,9}...}` there is a direct mapping to which entries appear in the set from which one it is in the list. Numbering from `0`:

```
0 = 0b = {}
1 = 1b = {1}
2 = 10b = {3}
3 = 11b = {1,3}
4 = 100b = {9}
5 = 101b = {1,9}
6 = 110b = {3,9}
7 = 111b = {1,3,9}
8 = 1000b = {27}
....
14 = 1110b
...
783 = 1100001111b
...
1125900981634049 = 100000000000000000001000000000100000000010000000001b
```

In this way by just analysing the bit pattern of the position of the set in the sequence you can determine which items should appear in the set. All you need then to do is work out the corrcet power of `3` for each bit that is set.

Using `BigInteger` because it's easy:

```
List<BigInteger> powerSubSet(long which, int power) {
    // The list I will build and return.
    List<BigInteger> l = new ArrayList<>();
    // A BigInteger version of the power required.
    BigInteger p = BigInteger.valueOf(power);
    // The bit pattern I will inspect.
    BigInteger bits = BigInteger.valueOf(which);
    // Roll each power out of the bit pattern.
    for (int i = bits.bitLength(); i >= 0; i--) {
        // A set bit means yes we want this one.
        if (bits.testBit(i)) {
            l.add(p.pow(i));
        }
    }
    return l;
}

private void test(long i) {
    System.out.println("powerSubSet(" + i + ",3) = " + powerSubSet(i, 3));
}

public void test() {
    test(14);
    test(783);
    test(1125900981634049L);
}
```

prints

```
powerSubSet(14,3) = [27, 9, 3]
powerSubSet(783,3) = [19683, 6561, 27, 9, 3, 1]
powerSubSet(1125900981634049,3) = [717897987691852588770249, 205891132094649, 3486784401, 59049, 1]
```

Note that you had `{1,9,27}` for `14`. I get `{3,9,27}` while we are the same on the others.